# Can't put GPU as Theano device in Windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x, theano, theano-cuda

My pc specs are a GPU NVIDIA 1050ti in a windows 10.

I installed the CUDA drivers (had to install visual studio with c++ tools) and run the tests, created a new conda environment with with theano and pygpu (python 3.6.3). Run the script:

```
from theano import function, config, shared, sandbox
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy
import time

print(config.device)


vlen = 10 * 30 * 768  # 10 x #cores x # threads per core
iters = 1000

rng = numpy.random.RandomState(22)
x = shared(numpy.asarray(rng.rand(vlen), config.floatX))
f = function([], T.exp(x))
print(f.maker.fgraph.toposort())
t0 = time.time()
for i in range(iters):
    r = f()
t1 = time.time()
print('Looping %d times took' % iters, t1 - t0, 'seconds')
print('Result is', r)
if numpy.any([isinstance(x.op, T.Elemwise) for x in f.maker.fgraph.toposort()]):
    print('Used the cpu')
else:
    print('Used the gpu')
```

Everything worked (with the cpu running).
Then I created a .theanorc.txt file and added to it:

```
#!sh
[global]
device = cpu
floatX = float32
```

I tried to run again the script and the result was.
5000 lines of some code followed by

```
    nvcc fatal   : Cannot find compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH

['nvcc', '-shared', '-O3', '-Xlinker', '/DEBUG', '-D HAVE_ROUND', '-m64', '-Xcompiler', '-DCUDA_NDARRAY_CUH=mc72d035fdf91890f3b36710688069b2e,-DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION,/Zi,/MD', '-I"C:\\Users\\JoaquimFerrer\\Anaconda3\\envs\\neural_nets\\lib\\site-packages\\theano\\sandbox\\cuda"', '-I"C:\\Users\\JoaquimFerrer\\Anaconda3\\envs\\neural_nets\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\include"', '-I"C:\\Users\\JoaquimFerrer\\Anaconda3\\envs\\neural_nets\\include"', '-I"C:\\Users\\JoaquimFerrer\\Anaconda3\\envs\\neural_nets\\lib\\site-packages\\theano\\gof"', '-L"C:\\Users\\JoaquimFerrer\\Anaconda3\\envs\\neural_nets\\libs"', '-L"C:\\Users\\JoaquimFerrer\\Anaconda3\\envs\\neural_nets"', '-o', 'C:\\Users\\JoaquimFerrer\\AppData\\Local\\Theano\\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_158_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-3.6.3-64\\cuda_ndarray\\cuda_ndarray.pyd', 'mod.cu', '-lcublas', '-lpython36', '-lcudart']
ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): Failed to compile cuda_ndarray.cu: ('nvcc return status', 1, 'for cmd', 'nvcc -shared -O3 -Xlinker /DEBUG -D HAVE_ROUND -m64 -Xcompiler -DCUDA_NDARRAY_CUH=mc72d035fdf91890f3b36710688069b2e,-DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION,/Zi,/MD -I"C:\\Users\\JoaquimFerrer\\Anaconda3\\envs\\neural_nets\\lib\\site-packages\\theano\\sandbox\\cuda" -I"C:\\Users\\JoaquimFerrer\\Anaconda3\\envs\\neural_nets\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\include" -I"C:\\Users\\JoaquimFerrer\\Anaconda3\\envs\\neural_nets\\include" -I"C:\\Users\\JoaquimFerrer\\Anaconda3\\envs\\neural_nets\\lib\\site-packages\\theano\\gof" -L"C:\\Users\\JoaquimFerrer\\Anaconda3\\envs\\neural_nets\\libs" -L"C:\\Users\\JoaquimFerrer\\Anaconda3\\envs\\neural_nets" -o C:\\Users\\JoaquimFerrer\\AppData\\Local\\Theano\\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_158_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-3.6.3-64\\cuda_ndarray\\cuda_ndarray.pyd mod.cu -lcublas -lpython36 -lcudart')
WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): The cuda backend is deprecated and will be removed in the next release (v0.10).  Please switch to the gpuarray backend. You can get more information about how to switch at this URL:
 https://github.com/Theano/Theano/wiki/Converting-to-the-new-gpu-back-end%28gpuarray%29

WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): CUDA is installed, but device gpu is not available  (error: cuda unavailable)
gpu
```

and then the output of the script running with cpu.
I added cl to the path and now I can run it in the console but the output didn't change.

Can someone help? Even with installing everything in a totally new way.